# Trouble with wordpress widgets attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm programming currently an online store. I'm using Wordpress. And as I have set it up from admin side widgets on my sidebar I attached attributes but when I attached to the web it's not being displayed. Cheers for the help up front.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to page template settings? For example :
[image]

This is my page template settings. If your page template setting doesn't have a sidebar menu you can't see it on the page. So can you check please the page template settings?

Comment: yes as I am creating the theme from scratch do you know maybe there is a tutorial how to make active product filter. which involves displaying all the attributes and tags so the person could chose what kind of product he is looking for ???

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ . Can you check the link. I hope the link helps you.